# How can I prevent an anchor from scrolling

Tags: jquery, html

I am using anchors and handle the click event in JQuery.

The href is set to "#"

Everything works fine except that the browser scrolls to the top when I click on the anchor. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure. You need to prevent the default action from occuring by either calling the [`event.preventDefault()` method](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) or by simply returning `false` from your event handler. You don't need both, but I'll show both here so you can see how it would fit with your existing code:

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // your other code here

    return false;
});
```

Note that returning false will also prevent the event from bubbling, i.e., it is the equivalent of calling both `.preventDefault()` and `.stopPropagation()`.